# Transaction Script and Unit of Work

Tags: design-patterns, nhibernate, unit-of-work, transactionscope, npgsql

We have a C# solution in which we applied the Transaction Script pattern; its layers are the following:

- Adapter: access point to the aplication (consumed by MVC Controllers and API Controllers); allways calls exactly one method from Logic layer;
- Logic: methods with business logic; inside each method we could have several calls to other logic/repository methods;
- Data Access: methods with calls to NHibernate and/or NPGSQL (for expensive operations requiring stored procedures)

Now, we want to implement the Unit of Work pattern using TransactionScope to use one and only one transaction per request (i.e.: one transaction per call to methods from Adapter, since we use UoW at Adapter level), but we can't figure out how to manage the connections, since we could have connections for NHibernate and/or NPGSQL inside the same method.

Regards

Comment: Have you seen [this](/q/646318/1178314), and [this](/q/5187860/1178314)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused... it sounds like you are using a single database, but then there is no reason to have a separate db connection for bypassing NHibernate. Just use the same one.

Using multiple connections would require distributed transactions to ensure correctness, and it's always easier and more performant if that can be avoided.

Example:

```
// Inside transaction...
{
    // Apologies if I didn't get the class name correct in cast.
    var conn = (NpgsqlConnection)session.Connection;
    conn.SomeDirectCall().
}
```

Depending on what your exact needs are, you may not even need the cast.

The only reason to use a separate connection should be if you explicitly want to AVOID doing it all in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction script is wider than the unit of work, the following image depicts the architecture of transaction script and suggests that unit of work lies within transaction script.

[image]